# Backbone JS Promises resolve before properties are set on model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Using a backbone model, assuming it fetches some additional properties from the server (like "FirstName" and "LastName"), I have something like the following:

```
var myModel = new Backbone.Model({ id: 10 });
var myOtherModel = new Backbone.Model({ id: 20 });
$.when(myModel.fetch(), myOtherModel.fetch()).done(function () {
    console.log(myModel.toJSON());
});
```

The output:

> { id: 10 }

The output a moment later:

> { id: 10, FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Schmo" }

It would seem that Backbone's promises are flawed in that the jqXHR object returned has a promise that's resolved prior to backbone completing its own process.

Is this the case?  Is there something else that must be done to ensure that the promise returned by `fetch()` isn't resolved until all of Backbone's `set`s are done, or at least the `set`s happen before my attached handler?

Comment: fetch returns the raw xhr object returned by jQuery. And unless I missed something, works for me http://jsfiddle.net/pUdFk/

Comment: @nikoshr Interesting!  Great proof via Fiddle (thanks for that).  I'll do some more research to see what might be different.

Comment: @nikoshr So I think what might be missing from this proof is that the "server" fetch doesn't set any properties.  The properties being output by console.log in your fiddle exist upon creation so there's nothing to change or prove missing.

Comment: One day, I should try to find how to tell jsfiddle to return some JSON. Would cheating by overriding parse suit you? If yes, still working :) http://jsfiddle.net/pUdFk/1/

Comment: @nikoshr I'd say that's unfortunately not definitive enough. :)

Comment: Overriding sync to get jsfiddle to return a new attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/pUdFk/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the issue.

My model that I was fetching overrode Backbone.Model.sync.

```
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
                    // Some stuff
        Backbone.sync(method, model, options); // missing return
    }
```

Because it didn't `return Backbone.sync()` the promise was resolving immediately.  I would have caught this if not for the `$.when()` wrapping the `fetch()` calls, which silently will accept any old thing, even if it's not a promise, and simply treat it as resolved immediately.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use the "success" callback in your fetch call?

```
myModel.fetch({
  success: function () {
    console.log(myModel.toJSON());
  }
});
```

Comment: Because that defeats the purpose of the question: using promises.  Promises are, by the way, far superior.